# Using Ajax in ASP.Net -- Non-Default Code Structure

Tags: asp.net, ajax

All, I want to add Ajax functionality to my Asp.net project. Currently I just need the basic partial Page update feature. I used ScriptManager and UpdatePanel in the Aspx Pages, the triggers is also set up correctly. However it does not work. I think it is because of the architecture of my application. The architecture is like this:

Assume two pages: Report1.aspx and Report2.aspx,

In the code behind files, Report1.aspx.cs and Report2.aspx.cs only have code like below:

`namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class Report1: Library.Report
    {
        }
}`

`namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class Report2: Library.Report
    {
        }
}`

And another file at the \Library\Report.cs have all the codes for the page business logic.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to narrow down your problem.  There is nothing wrong with your code structure, unless Library.Report does not inherit from the Page object.

Comment: Bryan, thanks for your reply. My problem is that I can not get the page partially updated. The page always fully refreshes. As I stated above, the Report.CS does inherit from the Page Object, although it does not directly inherit from the Page Object. And We are using Master Page in these pages. Also I am using AsyncPostBackTrigger. and I am sure the EventName is correct for the controls. All the controls are included in the UpdatePanel. No errors are reported when compiled but just does not partially update! Thanks!

Comment: Bryan, you are right. it has nothing to do with the Code Structure. I created an small project and tried it out. It works. I think it is because of the super classes of the page, which is old and complicated . I will keep looking. Thanks for your help!